# Security in returning arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function, memory-management, software-design

Suppose the following function:

```
float *dosomething(const float *src, const int N)
{
    float *dst = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    if(!dst)
    {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
           dst[i] = src[i] * 2;          
    return dst;
}
```

In this case we don't need allocate memory previously if we want to use it right?

Now, just another case:

```
void dosomething(float *dst, const float *src, const int N)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        dst[i] = src[i] * 2;
}
```

In the last case we need to allocate memory previously. So I share it and I'm wondering which is the best method for returning an array. Which of them provide more security to an user of the library or class? which method is most recommended? why?

Comment: `Best` for what? Btw, regarding your very wording, `security`, aren't you supposed to check the return pointer value from `malloc()` for equality to `NULL` before proceeding to dereference it? How about the possible overflow in `sizeof(float) * N`?

Comment: And stop casting the return value of `malloc` in C

Comment: @EdS. why? Sorry but I have always saw in the books, that I have got to apply casting.

Comment: Were those C++ books? If they were C books, they probably weren't good books.

Comment: older compilers needed the cast (~1970 to ~2000, so it is true you will see it in books), over time the compilers improve/change.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze most of them were C++. I don't remember the C books

Comment: So, that's why. In C++ the case is required, in C not.

Comment: @DarrylMiles: C89 didn't require a cast, so I'm not sure how you came up with that date range.

Comment: @facunvd: Because in C it is redundant; `void*` can be safely and implicitly converted to any other pointer type (in C++ this is not true).  Also, on pre-C99 compilers, it could hide an error.  If you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h` then `malloc` would be assumed to be a function returning `int`.  The cast hides that error and makes for interesting runtime problems.

Comment: Not all compilers supported a standard and not all OS libraries had standard headers.  Other memory models existed which impacted memory allocation.  I am only explaining why it might be read in books, this is not a comment on the merits of the cast itself.

Comment: @DarrylMiles: well sure, you can always pick up an out of date compiler, but I wouldn't say "(~1970 to ~2000)".  C89 has been implemented by most (all?) major compilers since well before 2000.  Fair enough though, I don't want to be overly pedantic here.

Comment: A fact I am not disputing, but we are agreeing that by 2000 (all?) major compilers would not need a cast.  So my comment as written still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's better practice or a better idea depends on what you're actually trying to do.

A function like `char *strdup(const char *s)` (POSIX) is implemented like the first case, it takes a string as an argument, allocates memory for another of the same length and then copies the source to the new piece of memory. It's *convenient* and saves you from manually doing the common action of allocating a buffer for the copy of the string. You could assume this is simply like a call to `malloc` and then `strcpy`/`memcpy`.

Then you've got a function like `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)`, which is like the second case, where you have control of where the string is going to be copied to. This way you're not forced into having the string copied into a dynamically allocated, not of your choice, piece of memory.

The first way might come in handy if you needed to create and initialise some sort of dynamic structure (list, tree, etc), but then again the second way also suffices and gives you control of what piece of memory is being used; you can use dynamically allocated memory on the heap, or local variables on the stack, etc.

Personally, I would usually go the second way, because I have more control of what variable's being initialised, and I'm not forced into having to use a newly `malloc`'d piece of memory (what if I wanted my local variable to be initialised?). You could always then write a wrapper function that makes a call to `malloc` and then to your function using the newly allocated memory as the destination.

It's really up to you and your design and what you're trying to achieve, there are no right and wrong ways and as long as you remember the allocated memory you shouldn't have any problems. I wouldn't say either of the two is more "secure."

Answer (score 1):

There is no RIGHT answer.

C language is inherently insecure, i.e. you can only make data secure if you make a copy and return the copy.  Thus hiding the real location of the original from the caller.

What is more important is how to handle the memory de-allocation of shared data that usually dictates the approach is more correct.

In the example you cite the only data being accessed is the data the caller has already passed (and already owns).  So the fact you allocate memory, do something with the data and return the allocated memory to the caller is just fine.  Just document that is how the function works (like strdup() works on C strings, the caller is responsible for using free() on any returned non-NULL pointer).

FWIW you don't "share" the data.  The caller invokes the function to do work on the data on its behalf, once the function returns no more access occurs.  If there was a retained (by the function) memory pointer (or other data) it would be correct to describe the situation as sharing data.  Since at some point in the future that retained memory pointer (or other data) maybe utilized in some way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite "this is better than the other". I never actually think about these things, and just do whatever comes to mind. Which is likely to be the more "natural" solution for the problem at hand. And if it turns out to be "bad" along the way... well, luckily we are not programming by engraving on stone tablets.

In your case, without knowing anything about the software at all, nothing "feels" better. That's actually quite common; almost everything you do in programming can be done in different ways, and often there's no actual difference other than personal preference or just random "that's what I came up with first".

For example, your second solution lets the caller copy to existing memory, which might be part of a larger object. On the other hand, he has to provide the destination memory every time. Although this could also mean saving allocations by using just one memory block for multiple calls. The first solution seems slightly more convenient for the simple case, but 'locks' the user in that case: there's always a fresh memory block allocated.